# how to display the current username in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

how to display the current username who executes the report in crystal report,
i have tried using CurrentCEUserName for displaying the current username, but it is not working. can anyone suggest me how to get this username into the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CurrentCEUserName` grabs the current username from the credentials that are used when connecting to the Business Objects Repository Server.

If you are looking to get the current user from a SQL Server that connects using Windows Authentication you will have to return the username value from the SQL Server to the Crystal Report.

e.g

```
Select SUser_SName() as [CurrentUser],
        Column1,
        Column2,
        etc..

From dbo.YourTable
```